# How much clusters must I use in elastic stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am confused which approach would be better having single cluster with 12 nodes or having 3 cluster with 4 nodes each in elastic stack. What are the advantages and disadvantages of single cluster? Does elastic charge me for 3 cluster as far as I know they charge for nodes but can someone clarify which would be better approach and which would be cost effective solution?

I am planning to use these nodes in my cluster :

master
data_content
data_hot
ingest
ml
remote_cluster_client

Comment: you should clarify about size of shards and index rate and search rate of indices that you want to put in each cluster.

Comment: if everything is equal it doesn't matter.

Comment: any idea if cost of using 3 cluster having 4 nodes each is same as having 1 cluster with 12 nodes ?

Comment: no. I dont know anything about cost of aws and elastic cloud.

Comment: Okay thanks for helping me with what u know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What the optimal cluster size is depends on various requirements / tradeoffs:

- Do you have multiple users / systems that you might want to isolate against each other (so that one running wild won't overload the cluster for everyone)? Then you might be better off with multiple clusters.
- On the other hand a single larger cluster would be able to absorb extra load from one user / system better.
- Smaller clusters are quicker to upgrade and you don't have one "big bang" upgrade. Or you might just upgrade some part but not everything at once.

2. Every cluster should have 3 master eligible nodes.
3. Most features in the Elastic Stack are free, but some are paid. Besides the cloud service where it's resource based, there are 2 modes for pricing:

- The classic node based pricing. Every Elasticsearch process would need a license. So larger nodes (within the technical limits) would cost you less than many smaller ones, but the cluster size itself doesn't matter.
- The newer pricing model for ECE / ECK is resource based where you buy chunks of memory and you can slice that into as many nodes or clusters as you want.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply .. I got some idea about this. Would you recommend dedicated nodes for ml and ingest ?

Comment: Maybe. I think we're generally recommending dedicated nodes from 6 to 10 nodes on; dedicated master nodes are also relatively high on that priority list. The reason why you might want to break out ingest and ML is because they can use a different hardware profile (lots of CPU, less memory, little disk/IO). So depending on your requirements it could be a win in terms of cost or an overkill.